# Why has the run time increased increased greatly for a programming problem after using NCalc and dictionary?

Tags: c#

I created a 45 line solution to the recursion problem listed at the bottom of this post. I then refactored it using NCalc and a dictionary to get it down to 13 lines. After the change, I noticed that the runtime went up from 13 seconds to 4 minutes and 9 seconds. What causes this huge increase in run time? and is it more important to keep run time down than it is to use less lines of code?

Original Version:

```
public static List<string> EquationsThatSumTo100LongVersionSolution()
    {
        var permutations = AllPermutationsForListOf8IntegersEachIntegerBeingOneTwoOrThree();
        var listOfEquations = new List<List<int>>();
        var equationStringsThatSumTo100 = new List<string>();
        foreach (List<int> list in combinations)
        {
            var equation = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                if (list[i] == 2)
                {
                    equation[i + 1] *= -1;
                }
                else if (list[i] == 3)
                {
                    var conjoinedDigits = "" + equation[i] + equation[i + 1];
                    equation[i + 1] = Int32.Parse(conjoinedDigits);
                    equation[i] = 0;
                }
            }
            if (equation.Sum() == 100)
            {
                var equationString = "";
                equation.RemoveAll(i => i == 0);
                foreach (int i in equation)
                {
                    if (i == equation[0])
                    {
                        equationString += i;
                    }
                    else if (i < 0)
                    {
                        equationString = equationString + " - " + (i * -1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        equationString = equationString + " + " + i;
                    }
                }
                equationString += " = 100";
                equationStringsThatSumTo100.Add(equationString);
            }
        }
        return equationStringsThatSumTo100;
    }
```

New Version:

```
public static List<string> EquationsThatSumTo100Solution()
    {
        var variables = new Dictionary<int, string>{{ 1, "+" }, { 2, "-" }, { 3, "" } };
        var permutations = AllPermutationsForListOf8IntegersEachIntegerBeingOneTwoOrThree();
        var equationsThatSumTo100 = new List<string>();
        foreach (List<int> list in permutations)
        {
            var equation = new String("1" + variables[list[0]] + "2" + variables[list[1]] + 
"3" + variables[list[2]] + "4" + variables[list[3]] + 
"5" + variables[list[4]] + "6" + variables[list[5]] + "7" + variables[list[6]] + 
"8" + variables[list[7]] + "9");
            if( Convert.ToInt32(new Expression(equation).Evaluate()) == 100)
                equationsThatSumTo100.Add(equation);
        }
        return equationsThatSumTo100;
    }
```

Programming problem:
Write a program that outputs all possibilities to put + or - or nothing between the numbers 1,2,…,9 (in this order) such that the result is 100. For example 1 + 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9 = 100.

Comment: `AllPermutationsForListOf8IntegersEachIntegerBeingOneTwoOrThree`.... method names are supposed to be a _short, concise description_ - not a 300-page novel. also: i don't really see any _recursion_ in your code?

Comment: "is it more important to keep run time down than it is to use less lines of code" - _guess_. once.

Comment: And the way you fix that long method name is by making `ListOf8Integers` a parameter to the method, and by writing validation code for `EachIntegerBeingOneTwoOrThree`.

Comment: `AllPermutationsForListOf8IntegersEachIntegerBeingOneTwoOrThree` Holy crap that's meme worthy.

Comment: With tongue firmly in cheek, it should really be named `AllPermutationsForListOf8CharactersWhereEachCharacterIsPlusMinusOrEmpty`.  Using the numbers 1, 2, and 3 to represent the desired characters introduces unnecessary confusion, since those characters will be going in the spaces between numbers (which include 1, 2, and 3).

Comment: About your real question - the performance difference: only you can answer that question.  You should either research performance/profiling tools, or else make use of things like `Stopwatch` throughout your functions to see where the time goes.  My suspicion? You seem to be looping over the same result of the `AllPermutations...` method in both code examples, so perhaps there is overhead in the call to `new Expression` or else its `Evaluate` method.

Comment: There is no recursion in your code.
Hints for performance decrease:
1. `List` vs `Dictionary`
2. New type: `Expression`

Also take a look at Sean's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed that long method name to VarCombos(I also realized that method is generating combinations not permutations).
After following Sean Skelly and CSakura's advice, I got rid of the dictionary and changed the output of VarCombos to a list instead of a dictionary. That cut down the run time to 1 minute and 3 seconds. Some stopwatches showed that 1 minute of that time is being consumed by the Evaluate method which is needed to solve the problem with less code.

Personally, I prefer the version with more code and a shorter run time over the version with less code and a longer run time.

Here's the new code

```
public static List<string> EquationsThatSumTo100Solution()
    {
        var combinations = VarCombos();
        var equationsThatSumTo100 = new List<string>();
        foreach (List<string> vars in combinations)
        {
            var equation = new String("1" + vars[0] + "2" + vars[1] + "3" + vars[2] + "4" + vars[3] + 
            "5" + vars[4] + "6" + vars[5] + "7" + vars[6] + "8" + vars[7] + "9");
            if( Convert.ToInt32(new Expression(equation).Evaluate()) == 100)
                equationsThatSumTo100.Add(equation);
        }
        return equationsThatSumTo100;
    }
```